# Does not navigate to another angular component after delete operation in atlas mongodb

Tags: angular, navigation, crud, mean-stack, mongodb-atlas

Scenario:
From View profile screen-- select an item-click to delete-after deleting from atlas mongodb- navigate back to View profile screen

Tech stack: Meanstack
Issue:
After successfully deleting the document from atlas mongodb, it does not navigate away.

```
onSubmitDeleteService(val: any) {
    console.log("Delete function called from delete service screen ");
   this.CptserviceService.DeleteServiceFromDeleteServiceForm(val).subscribe((res) => {
   this.router.navigate(['/myaccount']);
      console.log("Deleted selected service to mongo database successfully from  delete service screen:");
      
    },
      (err) => { console.log("Delete service  from delete service screen failed :", err) }
    )
  }
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when you submit the request and it is resolved successfully? I suspect your route name is not correct.

Comment: @Walid : No error. I found the answer. The delete operation was not giving the response to Angular service that's why it was not calling the navigation